# How to Display Custom View Modaly

Tags: iphone

I've written a small multiplayer game for the iphone. Once one of the players win, I want to display him 'You Win' image and a button so that he can play again.
How can this be done? One option is to use a segue to a new view-controller, but I think this should be shown with the game in the background. What would you suggest, as I'm pretty sure this is a common scenario for an iphone game/app.

EDIT: I ended up using both Phillip Mills's answer and Selkie's answer. Here is on   [How to Use UIView transitionWithView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144929/how-to-animate-sliding-from-bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the custom view and keep it as a separate property within your main game view controller.  When someone wins, add it as a subview to the `view` property of the controller.  It can be full screen size with transparency so that it's effectively modal, yet shows the game as background.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it as a view, then show it using `UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations`

The animation block could be sliding up, fading or whatever you want.

The other way is to add it at the beginning, but set its `hidden` property as `YES`. Change it to `NO` when it's needed.