# How to Use UIView transitionWithView?

Tags: iphone

I've written a small multiplayer game for the iphone. Once one of the players win, I want to display him 'You Win' image, which is in an ImageView. I want to make an animation that will show this UIImageView on top of the current game view with sliding from bottom animation. This UIImageView will fill the whole screen while using transparency to make it modal, so in the background I will still see the game state. How cam this be done using UIView transitionWithView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your view to be animated as someView. Initial frame of someView be bottomRect i.e., bottom of the view. final position be topRect.

```
//set initial frame
someView. frame = bottomRect;

// initially it will be completely transparent
SomeView. alpha=0.0;

// animationTime is time to complete animation
// delayTime is time delay after which animation will start
[UIView animateWithDuration: animationTime delay: delayTime options: UIViewAnimationCurvelineari
animations:^{
    someView. frame = topRect;
    someView. alpha = 1.0;
} 
completion:^(BOOL finished){
    NSLog(@"Done!");
}];
```

Comment: thanks a lot! what should I set bottomRect to be, while considering that someView's parent is gameView?

Comment: I dint get you. What does gameView have. Wat is its frame.

Comment: gameView fills the entire screen, as I wish someView will too.

Comment: So let me clarify, gameview is entire view and you have subview named someview in it?

Comment: Can you write down frame size of the view which you want to animate

Comment: I'm in landscape mode, so my gameView is (0,0, 300, 480) and I want that someView fill fill the entire screen on top of game view.

Comment: Okay. SomeView bottomFrame be (0,480,320,480) topFrame be (0,0,320, 480). Makes view come from bottom to top. Width and height can be based on your requirement.